# Kings bounty: Warriors of the north - What is this painting hiding?

Tags: kings-bounty-the-legend, kings-bounty-north

I've encountered this painting inside the catacombs in Verlon.

[image]

> If I remember right from "KB: The Legend" it used to be a secret passage here, but although I can interact with the painting nothing happens. Is this a bug or I'm missing something? Or.. the passage is not here this time?